# Time complexity to insert a node before the node pointed by some pointer in circular singly list of n nodes?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, computer-science, singly-linked-list

I think that it is O(N) because in a circular singly list the pointer visits n nodes so that node to be inserted precedes the current node.

Have I got it right?

Comment: To be more accurate the "searching to get to the right node" is O(N). If you've already got a pointer to the actual node you want to insert at, the actual creation of the new node and linking is O(1).

Comment: @wLui155, note that the OP says the inserted node will *precede* the current node. In a singly linked list you cannot do that in O(1). The searching is really a necessary part of the whole operation, as you search the node that precedes the given node.

Comment: Anyhow, Buddy, you got it right.

Comment: Good point, I misread the question.

Comment: @trincot it is possible in ```O(1)```, see my answer

Comment: @AbhinavMathur, we may say this takes O(*m*) complexity, where *m* is the (average) size of a node's data. Depends on whether this is allowed. Could be strange for the caller to see their node's data was altered.

Answer (score 0):

The usual traversal and insertion would take `O(N)` time. However, it can be done in `O(1)` as well, if the nodes can be modified.
Let the list look like `A -> B-> C -> D -> A`, we are given a pointer to `C`, and we have to insert `E`. Now, create a copy of `C` and insert it after `C` itself. The list now looks like `A -> B-> C -> C(copy) -> D -> A`. Now, we can modify the values of the original `C` node to store the values of `E` node, so the list now becomes `A -> B-> E -> C -> D -> A`. Since you've only created a node and inserted it in place, it takes `O(1)` time complexity.